# AJAX request not executing inside chrome alarm

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, alarm

I am fairly new to AJAX and recently I've implemented chrome alarm in my background script. Here is my background.js :

```
chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function(alarm) {
alert("Begin");
    $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "myURLhere",
         datatype : 'jsonp',
         crossDomain: true,
         success: function(res)
         { 
            alert('Success1');
         },
         error: function() {
            alert("Error occurs!");
        }
    });
alert("We're done");})
```

So the problem is that, without the alarm my ajax request was executing successfully but now its never going into the success part. I always get 3 alerts (Begin,Error occurs! and We're done) and I have been wondering why since past few days.

Here is my popup.js file where the alarms are being set.

```
var alarmClock = {

    onHandler : function(e) {
        chrome.alarms.create("myAlarm", {delayInMinutes: 0, periodInMinutes: 2} );
                window.close();
    },

    offHandler : function(e) {
        chrome.alarms.clear("myAlarm");
                window.close();
    },

    setup: function() {
        var a = document.getElementById('alarmOn');
        a.addEventListener('click',  alarmClock.onHandler );
        var a = document.getElementById('alarmOff');
        a.addEventListener('click',  alarmClock.offHandler );
    }}; document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {       alarmClock.setup(); });
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: to make a cors request you need the server to send back an "allow" header, check  your console log for CORS error

Comment: sadly, nothing is getting logged on the console and this request was executing successfully until I used alarms.